# Can you extract data from another excel workbook with a given title?

Tags: excel

For example, if I want to call cell `B6`, in sheet "Countries", in the file "Alpha", I can use the following code.

```
='[Alpha.xlsx]Countries'!B6
```

However, if I wanted the user to provide me any file name, say in cell `A1` in the workbook that is calling, can I alter this code to call any given file name? For example, if the file name was "Beta", the user would enter "Beta" in cell A1.

Comment: have you tried something  like  ='[' & A1 & '.xls*]Countries'!B6

Answer (score 0):

You can use **INDIRECT** ...

```
=INDIRECT("'[Alpha.xlsx]Countries'!B6")
```

... but there is a catch.  If the workbook you're referencing is not open, it will throw an error.

Someone may have another answer but that's about as good as it gets (as far as I know) without writing VBA to try and overcome it.